# Execute Java program from PHP

Tags: java, php, exec

I have a program written in Java which read a key and encode some file. And I have a code in PHP, which should run this Java program:

```
$s = "java -jar library/encrypt/Encrypt.jar encrypt filePath CTR";

$descriptorspec = array(
    0 => array("pipe", "r"),
    1 => array("pipe", "w"),
    2 => array("pipe", "w"),
);
$process = proc_open($s, $descriptorspec, $pipes, dirname(__FILE__));
```

Unfortunately Java program throws an Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size
```

In method:

```
private byte[] encrypt(byte[] plainText) throws Exception {
    byte[] ivBytes = new byte[16];
    new Random().nextBytes(ivBytes);

    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/" + encryptionMode + "/PKCS5Padding", "BC");
    SecretKeySpec keyy = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");

    // in next line Java throws exception
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyy, ivSpec);

    byte[] cryptograph = cipher.doFinal(plainText);
    return ArrayUtils.addAll(ivBytes, cryptograph);
}
```

But, Java program works correctly when I run it from command line. I run it with exactly the same parameters - and program encode file properly.

Why my program works correctly when I execute it from command line, and throws exception when I execute it from PHP? Any idea?

I run PHP on XAMPP on Windows.

Comment: _Illegal key size_ indicates that you don't have installed the unlimited strength file. Different results when running your Java program indicates that you run different VMs.

Comment: Do you think about Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files? I installed it a few days ago. Could you explained me how to run the same VMs?